# Ember component and dynamic attributes over iteration

Tags: javascript, ember.js

How can I add support to my custom Ember component for appending dynamic attributes and also action?
I have my custom component as

```
{{my-radiobutton name='myName' value='RadioButton1' selection=this.selectedRadio}}
```

Now I want to iterate over API response and have dynamic attributes in my template as well as action support as below;

```
{{#each model.myApi as |myApi|}}
{{#if someCondition}}
{{my-radiobutton name='myName_{{myApi.someId}}' value='someAction_{{myApi.someId}}' selection=this.selectedRadio {{action 'actionClicked'}}}}
{{else}}
{{my-radiobutton name='myName_{{myApi.someId}}' value='someAction_{{myApi.someId}}' selection=this.selectedRadio {{action 'actionClicked'}}}}
{{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

Is it possible to do that?

PS: I do not have control over the custom component my-radiobutton, since it is kind of common/external, so I'll prefer anything in the template or my controller

Comment: I think you could do it in the way a component was defined. Usually the definition is simple, you can just make a custom version. It should be an object, with properties as attributes, I don't remeber exactly.

Comment: my simple question is how do I append dynamic attribute values to my custom component as I iterate over the api resposne using each

Comment: Ohhh.... You simply find the element and setAttribute() on it. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp

Comment: hmm...but i need to do it dynamically...i.e. as I iterate...so do u mean i should do it entirely in the controller....Also remember I have a custom component {{my-radiobutton }} that I want to be rendered and not normal <input> tag

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for the [concat helper](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#method_concat)

```
{{#each model.myApi as |myApi|}}
  {{#if someCondition}}
    {{my-radiobutton name=(concat "myName_" myApi.someId) value=(concat "someAction_" myApi.someId) selection=this.selectedRadio {{action 'actionClicked'}}}}
  {{else}}
     {{my-radiobutton name=(concat "myName_" myApi.someId) value=(concat"someAction_" myApi.someId) selection=this.selectedRadio {{action 'actionClicked'}}}}
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Thx a lot...Is the concat helper included by default in Ember OR do we have to add manually ?

Comment: and just one more thing...Is it possible to add custom attributes to my custom component like data-somedata=myApi.someId and access it in the controller  ?

Comment: again...just to add..i do not have access to modifying the component itself

Comment: About the the concat helper, it's included by default

Comment: About the custom attributes, if your attributes are in that `|model.myApi|` and that is in the controller, sure. 
In your controller you can `this.get('model.myApi')` and get all those attributes back. If you pass them to the component, they're also available in the component.